# What is this error whenever I try to install mysql for python module?

Tags: python

I have tried 2 commands:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

and

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Error for the `pip install mysql-python`

```
Command "C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Programming\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Pops\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zfndvw17\\mysql-python
\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Pops\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-reco
rd-jpu7d9zb\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Programming\Python\venv\include\site\python3.7\mysql-python" failed with er
ror code 1 in C:\Users\Pops\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zfndvw17\mysql-python\
```

Error for the `pip install mysqlclient`

```
Command "C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Programming\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Pops\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cn_nm0np\\mysqlclient\
\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Pops\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-recor
d-lyzr49kh\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Programming\Python\venv\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient" failed with erro
r code 1 in C:\Users\Pops\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cn_nm0np\mysqlclient\
```

This is the download portion and seems to work fine until the end. (Just putting this here to fill-up more non-code text for stackoverflow to accept the revision)

Top portion prior to error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz (90kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 168kB/s
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Programming\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Pops\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-instal
l-cn_nm0np\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Pops\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-record-lyzr49kh\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Programming\Python\venv\include\site\python3.7\mysql
client:
    C:\Users\Pops\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.13 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -IC:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Pro
gramming\Python\venv\include -IC:\Users\Pops\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\Pops\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits
\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Win
dows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Try downloading `mysqlclient` module manually, extracting it and running `python ./setup.py` to see more detailed error messages.

Comment: Could you please post the part above the 'Command' error too?

Comment: @GRipepi added the other portions of the code in the main post.

Comment: @running.t Alright will I type `python ./setup.py` in the terminal?

Comment: do you have visual studio installed?

Comment: @NipunSampath yeah I do Visual Studio 2017 community

Comment: Do I have to add `cl.exe` to the path of windows manually?

Comment: You need to add the folder 'cl.exe'

Comment: @GRipepi Thanks doing it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add **cl.exe** into your **PATH**. It is generally located in **(visual studio folder)\VC\bin** directory. Add that to your PATH variable using the steps in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/737542/how-can-i-add-a-program-path-to-the-windows-environment-variables-for-easy-comma/737554#737554).
After this restart the command prompt and you can use cl.exe from command prompt.

**Alternatively** you can download unofficial windows binaries for mysqlclient from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient. And Install using **pip install "path to the downloaded whl file"**

Comment: Hi, I do not have a `bin` folder. The paths for mine are: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC` but there are no `bin` folders for both

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe
check this path

Comment: I don't have a `bin` folder after the `Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827` and inside the folders there's no `cl.exe`. I don't have a `14.10.25017` folder as well only the one stated above

Comment: search for VCVARSALL.BAT file. According to MSDN docs(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx) it will automatically add cl.exe to PATH.

Comment: Can't find that VCVARSALL.BAT file when I type it in the search box in My Computer

Comment: Will removing visual studio work? I don't need it anymore

Comment: It is a .bat file

Comment: Sorry revised the typo, but that was the one I searched

Comment: Removing VS won't work. It is needed for this. Alternatively you can try installing precompiled libraries from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174784/discussion-between-nipun-sampath-and-marc-santos).

Comment: go there and download mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl this (it's only 1.2 mb) and install using pip install "path to whl file"

Comment: thanks! It works now :) does this have any lost in functionality? How come the previous needed `cl.exe`?

Comment: Well these as far as I know those binaries are precompiled. Therefore they don't need to be recompiled in the installation process like the official ones. Therefore they don't need VS. You won't loose any functionality using this. They are just unofficial.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need to cl.exe folder.
You can do it through Visual Studio installer.
Install the following C++ compilers:

[image]

Comment: Still updating my VS installer will try it out in a while

Comment: Which ones specifically? All of those checked? That's a huge download

Comment: I know...ALL OF THEM

Comment: Thanks that is a waste of space. I read a similar post where people were complaining about 5GB worth of downloads